# Can't Add Large Icons to Asset Catalog

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

I am trying to add images for my app icon to my project using asset catalogs. My version of OSX is 10.9.3 and version of Xcode is 5.1.1. The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/AddingIconSets2/AddingIconSets2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH9-SW1) states that you can drag and drop your images into the set boxes in the Asset Catalogs folder. However, many of my drag and drop boxes are cut off and I cannot horizontally scroll:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? I couldn't find another way to add files to a specified size in an AppIcon set. Is there another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a bug; I've experienced the same thing — fullscreen on a 24" display [(even Apples Documentation shows it cut-off)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/AddingIconSets2/AddingIconSets2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH9-SW1). If you drag the images there it should still accept them though.

Comment: I'm dragging the images into the white space below and it adds it under a completely new section under "App Icon". Should I be dragging it somewhere else? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply fix this problem by hiding the side bar from the top of the screen. This will reveal all the image drops. Even so, just dropping the images in should auto-sort them into the right place

Comment: I clicked the sidebar button at the top and managed to reveal the 256 section, but still not 512 and 512@2x. When I dropped them in the white space, they don't go  into any of the placeholders, it creates a new section in the sidebar under "AppIcon". Any more ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, I know this is a really annoying bug as I always have this issue. Usually, by hiding both of the side bars, I can see everything, however, if you need more space, drag the entire window over to the left of the screen, and expand it so that it is bigger than the screen. Hope that helps :)

Comment: That works!! I opened up Xcode 6 Beta 2 and it looks like it is still broken. Will file a bug report later on. Thanks, again!

Comment: Did I answer your question?